How do I make top of the bump round instead of flat?
I'm making procedural citrus pulp textures.
I made it somewhat close to what I wanted but noticed that the top of each pulp is flat like they are squished against walls inside an invisible box. Could anyone help me fix this problem? I want to make round tops on each pulp.



Please read the instructions to upload a file at https://blend-exchange.com - you should have copied the whole text in that extra field and edited into your question to link to your file. Now you have just posted a link to the "Download the Blend" image.

Ok, I edited my question.  Thank you for the advice.

Do you want to use displacement or bump only? In your file, you are using a Displacement node and the material's setting "Displacement and Bump", but the default cube has not enough geometry for displacement (as you can see in the screenshot). The Scale for the displayment is way too high.

The "flat" areas are caused by values that are "out of range"/clamped. I would use a Float Curve node to smooth the Voronoi spikes instead of the 3 Math nodes that you use. Here is an example of displacement: https://i.sstatic.net/yrW8Wt50.jpg - Note: In Blender 4.1 or older, the displacement only works with Cycles. In Blender 4.2, Eevee and the Material Preview now also can render the displacement.

@Blunder that appears to be a complete answer. Please post it as such.

Thank you @Blunder that took care of my problem pretty well. If you could post your comment as answer, I'll choose your answer.
